# Extra text after the URL in a QR code

Tags: url, qr-code

I've seen a number of QR codes that contain a URL but also have extra some text after it.  Something like:

```
http://www.example.com   Thanks for scanning this QR code!
```

I've experimented with using a number of different delimiting methods (several spaces, a question mark, two dashes, one or two returns) and all work to varying degrees on various scanning programs.

Some respect the space character, others respect the return. Some think the URL isn't a URL at all when I use a return.  Long story short, it's all over the map how the various scanning programs (NeoReader, iNigma, Qrafter, Beetag, OptiScan, etc.) treat characters after a URL.

Is there any consensus on weather (a)this is even a good idea or not and (b)if so, what is the 'correct' (best practice) way to do it?  (I know I should go read the RFC for the exact definition of a URL but since the reader programs are all over the map, I suspect they didn't read it either.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spaces are definitely not part of a URL, so, in that sense a space definitely should delimit the end of a URL.

The entire string is not a URL, taken as a whole of course. So yes it's asking for trouble.

As you've found, the empirical answer is that not every reader does what you want. Barcode Scanner for instance understands the split here, but does not prompt the user to launch the browser since the payload isn't a URL per se.

So: it's a bad idea.

Answer (score 3):

You can make it work by converting the text message into valid URL, while trying to keep readability.

In your case it can be:

http://www.example.com?Thanks_for_scanning_this_QR_code

It's not perfect, but it can help on web analytics side to distinguish all QR code users.